How to fold python code using sed and/or awk?
I have a large python code base.  I want to get a feel of how a BaseClass is subclassed by 'grepping-out' the name of the sub class and the functions in the class, but only for classes that inherit from SomeBaseClass.
So if we have multiple files that have multiple classes, and some of the classes look like:
class SubClass_A(BaseClass):
    def foo(self):
        ...

    async def goo(self):
        ...

class AnotherClass:
    ...

class SubClass_B(BaseClass):
    def foo(self):
        ...

    async def goo(self):
        ...

If we apply some sort of scrip to this code, it would output:
File: /path/to/file
class SubClass_A(BaseClass):
    def foo(self):
    async def goo(self):
class SubClass_B(BaseClass):
    def foo(self):
    async def goo(self):

There can be many classes in the same file some of them may be a BaseClass. Essentially, this is like folding lines of code in an IDE.
Now, I tried using sed to do this, but I'm not an expert in it, and sed won't be able to print the file path.  However, I know awk can print the file path, but I don't know awk!  Argh.
I thought about writing a python program to do this, but this problem seems like something a nifty sed/awk program can do.
Thanks for the help.

Shouldn't async goo be async def goo?

Can't you do this with grep? Just match lines that begin with class, def, or async def, with optional whitespace at the beginning.

You are right.  Great eyes!! Let me edit that.  Thanks.

Most IDEs can also do this.

It doesn't present in the manner I specified.  At least not in pycharm.  I can search for the re 'class.*SomeBaseClass' and it will show the results of the search, but it won't show the function names as well.  There will be a preview window where you can see the entire file, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Try Code->Folding->Collapse All.

Using any awk, this may be what you're trying to do:
$ awk '/^class/{ f=/\(BaseClass)/ } f && $1 ~ /^(class|def|async)$/' file
class SubClass_A(BaseClass):
    def foo(self):
    async def goo(self):
class SubClass_B(BaseClass):
    def foo(self):
    async def goo(self):


This is probably good enough most of the time in practice, but it should be pointed out that Python allows you to put a newline after the opening parenthesis in the class definition, for example. For a really pathological example, you could have a backslash-escaped newline between any two tokens.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -nE '/^class/h;G;/\<(class|def)\>.*\n.*\(BaseClass\)/P' file

This is a filtering operation so use the -n option to not implicitly print lines.
Make a copy of any line beginning with class.
Append the copy to each line.
If the first line in the pattern space contains class or def and the second line contains (BaseClass), print the first line.

Standard library of python contains pyclbr which can be useful for that purpose, but be warned that it does following way

information is extracted from the Python source code rather than by
importing the module

Simple example, let myclasses.py content be
class A:
    def method_a(self):
        pass
class B(A):
    def method_b(self):
        pass
class C(B):
    def method_c(self):
        pass
class Z:
    def method_z(self):
        pass

then
import pyclbr
classes = pyclbr.readmodule('myclasses')
for name, data in classes.items():
    if data.super:
        print(name, "superclasses")
        for superclass in data.super:
            print("-", superclass.name)
    else:
        print(name, "has no superclasses")
    if data.methods:
        print(name, "methods")
        for method in data.methods:
            print("-", method)
    else:
        print(name, "has no methods")

gives output
A has no superclasses
A methods
- method_a
B superclasses
- A
B methods
- method_b
C superclasses
- B
C methods
- method_c
Z has no superclasses
Z methods
- method_z

Keep in mind that it does report B as parent of C and A as parent of B, but not A as parent of C.
(tested in python 3.10.12)
